# ValueError in clustering evaluation: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead

Tags: scikit-learn, k-means

```
df_2D = df[['sepal-length', 'petal-length']]
df_2D = np.array(df_2D)
k_means_2D_model = KMeans(n_clusters=3, max_iter=1000).fit(df_2D)
```

Error:

```
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[0 1 0 0 2 2 1 2 1 1 0 1 0 2 0 2 1 2 0 2 2 1 0 1 2 0 0 2 1 0 2 0 1 1 0 0 2
 1 2 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 2 1 2 2 0 2 2 2 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 2 1 2 1 2 2 1 2 1 0 0 2 1
 1 0 2 0 0 1 1 0 1 2 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 2 1 1 1 2 0 2 0 0 2 2 0 0 1 2 2 1 0
 2 2 1 1 2 0 0 2 2 2 0 0 1 0 1 0 2 2 2 0 0 0 0 2 1 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 2 2 0 0 0
 1 0].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

Comment: Please post a [mre], which should be straightforward with the `iris` data you seem to be using; do not post any code that comes *after* the error. Here probably the issue is the unnecessary `df_2D = np.array(df_2D)`, which converts the data into a 1D array.

Comment: This code actually work. You might have override the variable `df_2d` in your jupyter notebook...

Comment: I adjusted my environment and it works now. Thanks